# Why does Safari not update the anchor link?

Tags: html, href

I have two links on my home-page. They point to two different anchor tags (anchor1, anchor2) on the about-page.

When I click on link two, it jumps to anchor2 on the about page. If I go back and then click on link one, it still jumps to anchor2 on the about page.

I can confirm that  the link in the address bar always stays the same as the first clicked link. A simple reload does not solve the problem. What does seem to reset the situation is if I open the home-page in a new window or tab.

This is only happening on Safari and Safari Mobile. Firefox and Chrome redirect to the correct anchor tag.

Thos are the two links:

```
<a href="../about.html#anchor1">Anchor1</a>
<a href="../about.html#anchor2">Anchor2</a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have elements with the id `#anchor1` and `#anchor2` on your `about.html` page right ?

Comment: Yes thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that for the anchor-links to work in this context, they have to be written as full URL, not relative to the folder structure.

This 
`href="https://website.com/about#anchor1"`

Instead of this 
`href="../about.html#anchor1"`