# Anchor link to div on the same page not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a React based website that includes this list of links on the top of every page:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#contactSection">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

At the bottom of the home page I have this piece of HTML:

```
<section id="contactSection" className="contactSection ptb_100">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    ...HTML FORM...
</section>
```

When I click the Contact Us link from the top of the home page, Chrome will scroll to the correct HTML identified by the `contactSection`, however, Safari will scroll to the top of the page. When I click the Contact Us link from another page on the site, or if I type the `#contactSection` into the address bar and hit enter, Safari correctly scrolls.

I have looked at threads suggesting to add the `/` to the href, but that didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE** The cause of the issue was a sticky header on the top of the page that caused Safari to keep the page at the top. Removing the sticky header, solved the issue, although not sure why.

Comment: Given the preceding slash, is it looking for #contactSection at the webroot instead of the current page? (assuming the current page is not the home page). Or, do you have a scrollspy function loaded on that page and/or fixed-position elements (such as a sticky menu)?

Comment: The link works when it is clicked from any page except the home page, which is also the page that contains the `#contactSection`

Answer (score 2):

**You shouldn't add "/" for same page id links**

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#myDiv {
  /* To enable scroll */
  margin-top: 3000px;

  /* Extras (Not required) */
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#myDiv">
    Click mo to go to myDiv!
</a>

<div id="myDiv">This is myDiv</div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with React

Comment: So do I need to check the current page to determine if I should add the `/`? The link needs to be valid from all pages on the website including the home page, which is where it links to

Comment: Update: I tried removing the `/` so that the HTML just uses `#contactSection`, but it still didn't work. I see that your example works when I run it in Safari, so does the element I am trying to scroll to need to be a `div`? Or is there some other requirement about the element I am trying to link to?

Comment: @StevenLengieza [Maybe this explain your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58824737/why-does-safari-not-update-the-anchor-link#answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (edited according to the comment below)

in HTML:

```html
<li>
  <a href="#contactSection" onclick="scrollToElement('#contactSection')">CONTACT US</a>
</li>
```

and in JS:

```js
// kicks in if href doesn't work
function scrollToElement(id) {
  const el = document.querySelector(id);
  if (el) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
  }
}

// when redirected to the page from somewhere else
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const { href } = window.location;
  if (href.lastIndexOf('#')) {
    const id = href.substring(href.lastIndexOf('#'), href.length);
    scrollToElement(id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Avoid, this is not an accessible solution for several reasons: 1. The span element is not semantically correct for a link, will not receive keyboard focus and will not be announced as a link to screen readers. 2. Simply scrolling to the element is not an accessible solution for an anchor link as keyboard/screen reader focus needs to be moved. This solution will have no noticeable effect at all for a screen reader user. This also won't work when linking to the page from other places like anchor links should work. It's best to use real links wherever possible for this reason